# Ajax Jqgrid Reload Grid not Working c# .net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I'm using an web method to get an json response, but the Refresh button in the grid doesn't work.

This is the code Behind:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string getData()
{
    string data = GetJson();
    return data;
}

public static string GetJson()
{
    List<NameData> dataList = new List<NameData>();

    NameData data1 = new NameData();
    data1.pkNameID = 1;
    data1.Name = "Name_One";
    dataList.Add(data1);

    NameData data2 = new NameData();
    data2.pkNameID = 2;
    data2.Name = "Name_two";
    dataList.Add(data2);

    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    return js.Serialize(dataList);
}

public class NameData
{
    public int pkNameID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the ajax script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        GetData();
    });

    function GetData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ListTest.aspx/getData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            //async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                var item = $.parseJSON(response.d);
                if (item != null && item != "" && typeof (item) != 'undefined') {

                    $("#list").jqGrid({
                        url: 'ListTest.aspx/getData',
                        data: item,
                        datatype: 'local',
                        colNames: ['pkNameID', 'Name'],
                        colModel: [
                        { name: 'pkNameID', index: 'pkNameID', width: 30, align: 'left', stype: 'text', editable: false },
                        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 80, align: 'left', stype: 'text', editable: true }],
                        rowNum: 5,
                        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                        pager: '#pager',
                        sortname: 'pkNameID',
                        sortorder: 'desc',
                        caption: "Test Grid",
                        viewrecords: true,
                        async: false,
                        loadonce: false,
                        gridview: true,
                        width: 500,
                        edit: true,

                        loadComplete: function (result) {
                            //alert(jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records'));
                        },
                        loadError: function (xhr) {
                            alert("The Status code:" + xhr.status + " Message:" + xhr.statusText);//Getting reponse 200 ok
                        }
                    }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true });


                }
                else {
                    var result = '<tr align="left"><td>' + "No Record" + '</td></tr>';
                    $('#list').empty().append(result);
                }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

So, When i try to click in the refresh button(I need a Server Refresh), the grid doesn't refresh. I try change the datatype: 'local' to datatype: 'json' but this get error code: 200. I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks for you future help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't work because you create the table inside the "success" of the ajax call.
I'd suggest either to add a custom refresh button that calls the getData function (add $("#list").GridUnload() at the beginning of the function) or to make the ajax call inside the jqgrid instantiation.
The first way should be easier, although less elegant.
Following an example for the second solution without the refresh button, but it should be easy to add it to this code:

```
$("#resTable").jqGrid({
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'POST',
        url: "../WS/myServices.asmx/GetData",
        postData: "{firstParam:" + JSON.stringify(firstParam) +
        ", secondParam:" + JSON.stringify(secondParam) +
        ", thirdParam:" + JSON.stringify(thirdParam) + "}",
        loadonce: true,
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            root: function (data) {
                if (data && data.d.length > 0) {
                    return data.d;                    
                }
                else
                    alert("No result");
            }
        },
        ajaxGridOptions: {
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: 'post',
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result.responseText);
            }
        },
        colModel: [
            { label: 'Action', name: 'act', width: 100, sortable: false },
            { label: 'Col1', name: 'Col1', width: 250, sortable: false, key: true },
            { label: 'Col2', name: 'Col2', width: 350, sortable: true },
            { label: 'Col3', name: 'Col3', width: 120, sortable: false },
            { label: 'Col4', name: 'Col4', width: 120, sortable: false, hidden:true }
        ],
        height: 'auto',
        loadComplete: function () {
            var ids = jQuery("#resTable").jqGrid('getDataIDs'); //get the row IDs
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                var funct = "javascript:someFunction('" + ids[i] + "');";
                be = '<input type="button" class = "Btn" value="Do something" onclick="' + funct + '"  />';
                jQuery("#resTable").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { act: be });
            }
        },
        beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) { 
            return false; //to avoid selecting
        },
        hoverrows: false, //to avoid hovering
        caption: "My table"
    });
```